# Can't change the build platform from Any CPU to x86

Tags: visual-studio

Using visual studio 2008, i created an empty windows project. in the properties page of the project, build tab, i only have Any CPU as an option to select for the Platform.

I need to set the platform to x86. any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

Use "Create Platform" and "Copy from Any CPU"

Comment: Set the Platform target to x86 on `Right click Project > Properties > Build tab > Platform Target`, then use the Configuration Manager to create platform.